# Gantt chart on excel VBA code review and optimization

Tags: excel, vba, excel-charts

I made an excel gantt chart with the help of VBA. It is my first VBA project and I did my best to make it clean and organized however I think a lot of optimizations could be done.

I would like to ask you guys if you could take a look at some parts of my code that I have identified as the slowest and tell me if there is a better way : (Screenupdate, calculationautomatic, events, animation are all off and all my variables are declared as public and calculated in an other module)

The overall macro runs in 1s. I know it isn't that long but it is called everytime a change is manually made on the sheet. So I'd like to bring it down as much as possible.

Macro 1 takes about 0.2s in a 1s overall macro

```
Sub emptycells ()
' 
' This macro empty the cells after finding some text in a row

For i = 1 To X

If IsEmpty(Cells(line + i, col1)) = False Then

coltext = WorksheetFunction.Match(Cells(line + i, col1), Range(Cells(line + i, col2), Cells(line + i, col3)), 0)
Dim rngcelltext as Range
Set rngcelltext = Cells(line + i, coltext)
Range(rngcelltext, rngcelltext.End(xlToRight)).ClearContents

End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Macro 2 takes about 0.25s in a 1s overall macro
[Top line is the one added by this macro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Br9CS.png)

```
Sub addweeknb()
'
' Weekline is the line N° of the second line in the picture, colweek1 is the first column of that line, rngweek is the whole line
' This macro add a line with week number on top of the time line

For i = firstweek To lastweek

numcol1 = WorksheetFunction.Match(i, rngweek, 1) 'find the column nb 
nbcol = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rngweek, i)
Set rngweek_i = Range(Cells(weekline, colweek1 + numcol1 - nbcol), Cells(weekline, colweek1 + numcol1 - 1))
    With rngweek_i
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
        With rngsemi.Font
        .Name = "Calibri"
        .Size = 12
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontMinor
    End With
    rngweek_i.Merge
    rngweek_i.Font.Bold = True
    rngweek_i = i

Next i

End Sub
```

Edit : I managed to bring Macro 2 down to between 0.05s and 0.08s just by cleaning it a bit :

Revised Macro 2 :

```
Sub addweeknb()
'
' Weekline is the line N° of the second line in the picture, colweek1 is the first column of that line, rngweek is the whole line
' This macro add a line with week number on top of the time line

For i = firstweek To lastweek

numcol1 = WorksheetFunction.Match(i, rngweek, 1) 'find the column nb 
nbcol = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rngweek, i)
Set rngweek_i = Range(Cells(weekline, colweek1 + numcol1 - nbcol), Cells(weekline, colweek1 + numcol1 - 1))
   With rngweek_i
     .MergeCells = True
     .Font.Name = "Calibri"
     .Font.Size = 12
     .Font.Bold = True
     .Font.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
     .Value = i
End With

Next i

End Sub
```

Macro 3 takes about 0.45s in a 1s overall macro

```
Sub dimgant()
'
' This macro resize the gantt chart
'

' copi the conditional formula in the gantt area as it is now
Range(Cells(firstlinegantt, firstcolgantt), Cells(lastlinegantt, lastcolgantt)) = _
        "=MyFormula"


' Add lines to a liste with matricial formula in excel. It must match the number of line of the gantt
rngfirstlinematformula.AutoFill Destination:=rngmatformule, Type:=xlFillDefault

' Add column if graph goes less than 10 days after the latest date of the project
If lastcolgantt - firstcolgantt < nbofcolumnneeded + 10 Then
rnglastcol.AutoFill Destination:=Range(rnglastcol, Range(Cells(firstlinegantt, lastcolgantt), Cells(lastlinegantt, nbofcolumnneeded + 10))), Type:=xlFillDefault
End If

' Delete column if graph goes further than 10 days after the latest date of the project
If lastcolgantt - firstcolgantt > nbofcolumnneeded + 10 Then
Range(Cells(1, nbofcolumnneeded + 10), Cells(lastlinegantt, lastcolgantt)).Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
End If


End Sub
```

Thank you all very much.

Comment: Hi @remyfra - this question might be better suited for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) rather than Stack Overflow.

Comment: Hi @SamuelEverson, Thank you for this advise. I didn't know about Code Review. For now I just went around the issue by adding a tick box allowing to activate or desactivate the automatique call of the macro.

Comment: Hello, I found what was slowing down my macro so I though I'll update this post. The Macro 3 was inserting a formula in a big range (the gantt chart). This formula were returning values from 1 to 9 depending on conditions (long formula with a lot of IFs) and then these values were used to do a conditional formating of the cell. This is what was taking long. The conditional formating in excel. So I deleted that part and now do the formating straight from VBA. It's faster, more flexible and easier to manage!